# Install service and add registry entry under Vista+

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation, registry, uac

I have a program that runs as a desktop application, but can also be installed as a windows service. The installation is done by using an "install as service" button on the GUI. The event handler for this button looks like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("sc", "description " + 
   this.ServiceName + "  \"" + 
      ((AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description + "\"") 
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

What I would like to do now is to add some additional registry entries under say:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\MyCompany\Services
```

which also needs elevated privileges. But if I use the same procedure as described above with the command "REG ADD" the UAC dialog would appear more than once - and I don't want that.

So whats the best way to install a windows service and add a registry entry under HKLM with only having the UAC prompt once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling myself with admin priviliges and a special parameter `myprogram.exe -i` and then branch into a special method which uses the `ServiceInstaller` class to install the program as a service (instead of calling sc).

Answer (score 1):

Create a small exe or a batch file that does both things (the sc and the reg update). Launch *that* instead of sc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems like the obvious solution, but I want to avoid this, because the code is in a shared library. It would complicate deployment, if I have to rely on an additional componenent such as a batch file or an exe.

Answer (score 1):

As for installing service.
You can try [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/). It is easy to use and very powerful.